# Parse DateTime from Object with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to parse the year column to datetime.

```
    name    id  nametype    recclass    mass (g)    fall    year                    
0   Aachen  1   Valid       L5         21.0         Fell    01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM

... reclat      reclong     GeoLocation
... 50.77500    6.08333    (50.775000, 6.083330)
```

`df['year'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse)` and that parses as `1880-01-01 00:00:00` but i can use that for selecting dates. 
Do anyone have a tip for me?

Answer (score 2):

I think need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':['01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM']})

df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'])
print (df)
        year
0 1880-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have converted the `year` column to `datetime`, you can use:

```
df['year'] = df['year'].dt.date
# year    
# 1880-01-01
```

However, for datetime casting, note that pandas has an inbuilt [datetime parser](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) that is easy to use than `dateutil` IMO.

Comment: Thanks but this didnt work.
Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: You mentioned that you did `df['year'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse) ` which makes the `year` column a datetime column. This assumes that it is the case.